# can someone tell me why the session is not working

Tags: flask-session

I had a flask server running some service, but the session is not working

```
#
#app.secret_key="dosomething"
#
def login_authenticate():

    //do some thing
    session['user'] = 'foo'

def get_session():
    if 'user' in session:
        print("you have logged in")
        return session['user']
    else:
        print("not logged in")
        return 'not logged in!'
```

after I call the login_auth, a session should be set up, and when I try to call the get_session, it tells me not logged in

Answer (score 0):

You did not define a `secret_key` for your application. In this case, you will lost your session content after every page refresh. To solve this issue, you need to define a `secret_key` for your application in the main file:

```
app = Flask('application')
app.secret_key = "some secret key"
```

Comment: I have defined a secret_key in my __init__.py, but that doesn't work. So I think, maybe my app doesn't get correctly configured due to the file structure or something.

Comment: Does using this: if session.get('user'): make a difference ?